# Notifications iOS 10 working building with Xcode but no with phone

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase to handle notifications and once I have the notification I create a local notification (ios 9) or notification request (ios 10). All works well when I **Build** with Xcode and then **Run**, app receives notifications and it's shown.

But the problem is when I stop running the app through Xcode and I open, the notifications seems that never arrives in ios 10 version (but in ios 9 notifications are received as the first case without any problem).

1. Push notifications in Capabilities enabled, background modes too.
2. UserNotifications framework added

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I initialized all well:

```
 /* NOTFICATIONS */

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self


        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions(authOptions, completionHandler: { (_, _) in })

        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification(_:)), name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification, object: nil)
```

I  have UserNotification protocols implemented.

And I receive notifications here (in ios9 and ios10 i think, **This could be where I'm wrong so maybe the notifications in ios10 are not handled directly here. But in this case how it's possible that I receive the notifications when app is running through xcode**):

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification


    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo["gcmMessageIDKey"] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }


    let notificationJSON = JSON(userInfo)
    self.presentNotification(withNotificationJSON: notificationJSON)

    FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    completionHandler(.NewData)
}
```

By the other hand I have my file .entitlements but with development (maybe need a release ones? Or it change by herself when compile?)

Thank you so much i'm a bit frustrated, any further information you need just let me know.

**EDIT1:**

Maybe the problem could be in the parameters?

```
let notificationsParameters:[String:AnyObject] = [
        "to": "iphoneID",
        "content-available":true,
        "priority":"high",
       "notification" : [
           "sound" : " "
       ],
        "data" : [
            "Nick" : "Mario",
            "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: what do you mean by "but no with phone"?

Comment: Yes I think this is the strange part. When you run your app through Xcode it will be downloaded to your phone and you can debug your app via console. Once you stop the app through stop button on Xcode or unplugging USB. So now you have installed the app but you don't have "connected" the app with Xcode. Do you understand now? @nikdange_me

Comment: first case : running your app on iPhone connected to your Xcode project with USB cable & second case simply running app on iPhone. Right?

Comment: Correct @nikdange_me

Comment: how do you check if you are getting notification or not??

Comment: Basically, I genereate a local notification once notification arrives. By the way, I try it to debug increasing +1 the badge of the app icon badge everytime that didReceiveRemoteNotification is called. But in the second case never increase the badge. Is hard to debug without the debugger, so this is the hard part :(

Comment: sorry, but to make sure "i hope in both cases your device is in active mode/state" :|

Comment: what do  you mean with in active mode/state?

Comment: if app is running or screen is visible then it active mode!!

Comment: i am not able to understand what may the reason for your issue, if you get any other hint do inform!